# How to Rank a Partition in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to give each combination of CardId and InvoiceNo a Number/Rank for the below data

```
;WITH Test (CardId,InvoiceNo,Category,Amount) as 
(
    SELECT '1001','3001','Fees',30
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1001','3001','Non-Fees',45
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1001','3001','Service Fees',55
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1002','3002','Fees',10
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1002','3002','Non-Fees',25
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1002','3002','Service Fees',10
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1003','3010','Fees',45
    UNION ALL   SELECT '1003','3010','Non-Fees',70


)
```

Like this

```
CardId  InvoiceNo   Amount  Rank
1001    3001         30     1
1001    3001         45     1
1001    3001         55     1
1002    3002         10     2
1002    3002         25     2
1002    3002         10     2
1003    3010         45     3
1003    3010         70     3
```

I tried the below query with both `Row_number()` and `Rank()` but is not giving me the desired result. The `rank()` is ranking all the rows as 1 and the `row_number()` is numbering each group with 1,2,3.

```
SELECT CardId
,InvoiceNo
,Amount
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CardID,InvoiceNo ORDER BY CardId) as RankNo

FROM Test
```

Comment: Try removing `PARTITION BY CardID,InvoiceNo` and see what you come up with. I removed it and I think the results could be what you are looking for. The rankings are 1,4 and 7 respectively for the CardID...

Comment: Correction... change it to `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CardId, InvoiceNo) as RankNo` and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the partitions. The rank function looks *within* the partitions where a new partition resets the rankings. Thus it was seeing every record within each partition as tied for 1st. Also, you may want `dense_rank()`.

```
SELECT CardId
    ,InvoiceNo
    ,Amount
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CardId, InvoiceNo) as RankNo    
FROM Test
ORDER BY CardId, InvoiceNo, Amount
```

Fiddle:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f0c2/7

Comment: I ran your example code against the provided test case, and RankNo is still coming up as 1 for all rows. Might be worth a double-check.

Comment: I did some experimentation and you might try `DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY CardId, InvoiceNo) as RankNo`. It looks like the partition is what's breaking it.

Comment: @lyrisey better now

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT CardId
    ,InvoiceNo
    ,Amount
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CardId, InvoiceNo) as RankNo

FROM Test
```